# Emacs: How to enable a mode globally?

Tags: emacs, configuration, mode, minor-mode

I just have a mode from an [addon](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightIndentation) which I want to enable globally. In order to turn on it by hand I need to enter <kbd>M-x highlight-indentation-mode</kbd>. So, below is a list of what I have tried yet: `(highlight-indentation-mode t)`, `(highlight-indentation-mode 1)`, `(setq highlight-indentation-mode t)`. Nothing worked. Next I figure out that may be I need to enable a mode globally, and I started google about it. What I have tried next:

```
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-indentation-mode highlight-indentation-mode
  (lambda () (setq highlight-indentation-mode t)))
```

No, this surely aren't the droids I am looking for, it turns on the variable, but a mode still doesn't work.

```
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-indentation-mode highlight-indentation-mode
  (lambda () highlight-indentation-mode t))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-indentation-mode highlight-indentation-mode
  (highlight-indentation-mode t))
```

These two just broke my Emacs: when I tried open file with this two commands in config, Emacs wrote an error, and refused to open a files.

UPD: Based on comments I also tried

```
(defun enable-highlight-indentation-mode ()
  (interactive)
    (highlight-indentation-mode t))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-indentation-mode highlight-indentation-mode
  enable-highlight-indentation-mode)  

(global-highlight-indentation-mode t)
```

And the same without `(interactive)`. When I am try to open a file with this, Emacs refuse to open, and write an error:

```
File mode specification error: (void-function nil)
c-font-lock-fontify-region: Symbol's function definition is void: nil
```

Comment: The following link contains an example of how to create a global mode for semi-older Emacs versions:  http://superuser.com/a/762495/206164  The developer build of Emacs (not yet released as a stable public release) has an option for `:global t`  Essentially, for a semi-older Emacs version, you just need a small function to turn on the minor mode and name that function in your globalized . . . statement.  Your second example looks very close except that you didn't wrap `highlight-indentation-mode t` in parentheses.

Comment: `(defun turn-on-highlight-indentation-mode () (highlight-indentation-mode 1)) (define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-indentation-mode highlight-indentation-mode turn-on-highlight-indentation-mode)`

Comment: @lawlist I tried. Results I wrote in update.

Comment: A function is usually void because the parentheses after the function name are missing.  **CORRECT**:  `(defun turn-on-highlight-indentation-mode () (interactive) (highlight-indentation-mode 1))`  **INCORRECT**:  `(defun turn-on-highlight-indentation-mode (interactive) (highlight-indentation-mode 1))`  It may not necessarily be this new function that has the error -- it may be a different function in your configuration that is missing some parentheses.

Comment: Enable broader debugging with:  `(setq debug-on-error t)`  That may give you the name of the function that is causing the problem.

Comment: @lawlist now it writes `Entering debugger...    
c-font-lock-fontify-region: Symbol's function definition is void: nil`

Comment: I would take a good hard look at the function `c-font-lock-fontify-region` to see where it may have an error.  In some very rare circumstances one function might be missing a closing parentheses and the function underneath it has an extra closing parentheses -- so you want to make sure each function beginning has a matching ending, in addition to an obvious error like missing parentheses after the function name.

Comment: @lawlist doesn't seems that a problem somewhere farther than my config, because when I commented out the call `;(global-highlight-indentation-mode t)` all worked just fine. And btw: I have no idea, what is this function `c-font-lock-fontify-region`, and where it is could be.

Comment: Is it the one by Anton Johansson?  If so, the one in the answer below seems to work okay.  I added the global mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```lisp
;;; highlight-indentation.el --- Minor modes for highlighting indentation
;; Author: Anton Johansson <anton.johansson@gmail.com> - http://antonj.se
;; Created: Dec 15 23:42:04 2010
;; Version: 0.6.0
;; URL: https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs
;;
;; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
;; modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
;; published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of
;; the License, or (at your option) any later version.
;;
;; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be
;; useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
;; warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
;; PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
;;
;;; Commentary:
;; Customize `highlight-indentation-face', and
;; `highlight-indentation-current-column-face' to suit your theme.

;;; Code:

(defgroup highlight-indentation nil
  "Highlight Indentation"
  :prefix "highlight-indentation-"
  :group 'basic-faces)

(defface highlight-indentation-face
  ;; Fringe has non intrusive color in most color-themes
  '((t :inherit fringe))
  "Basic face for highlighting indentation guides."
  :group 'highlight-indentation)

(defcustom highlight-indentation-offset 4
  "Default indentation offset, used if no other can be found from
major mode. This value is always used by
`highlight-indentation-mode' if set buffer local. Set buffer
local with `highlight-indentation-set-offset'"
  :group 'highlight-indentation)

(defvar highlight-indentation-current-regex nil)

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode highlight-indentation-mode
  "Highlight indentation minor mode highlights indentation based
on spaces"
  :lighter " ||"
  (when highlight-indentation-current-regex ;; OFF
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil `((,highlight-indentation-current-regex
                                      (1 'highlight-indentation-face)))))

  (set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-current-regex) nil)

  (when highlight-indentation-mode ;; ON
    (when (not (local-variable-p 'highlight-indentation-offset))
      (set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-offset)
           ;; Set indentation offset from highlight-indentation-offset if set, otherwise
           ;; according to major mode
           (cond ((and (eq major-mode 'python-mode) (boundp 'python-indent))
                  python-indent)
                 ((and (eq major-mode 'python-mode) (boundp 'py-indent-offset))
                  py-indent-offset)
                 ((and (eq major-mode 'python-mode) (boundp 'python-indent-offset))
                  python-indent-offset)
                 ((eq major-mode 'ruby-mode)
                  ruby-indent-level)
                 ((and (eq major-mode 'scala-mode) (boundp 'scala-indent:step))
                  scala-indent:step)
                 ((and (eq major-mode 'scala-mode) (boundp 'scala-mode-indent:step))
                  scala-mode-indent:step)
                 ((or (eq major-mode 'scss-mode) (eq major-mode 'css-mode))
                  css-indent-offset)
                 ((eq major-mode 'nxml-mode)
                  nxml-child-indent)
                 ((eq major-mode 'coffee-mode)
                  coffee-tab-width)
                 ((eq major-mode 'js-mode)
                  js-indent-level)
                 ((eq major-mode 'js2-mode)
                  js2-basic-offset)
                 ((local-variable-p 'c-basic-offset)
                  c-basic-offset)
                 (t
                  (default-value 'highlight-indentation-offset)))))
    (set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-current-regex)
         (format "\\( \\) \\{%s\\}" (- highlight-indentation-offset 1)))
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil `((,highlight-indentation-current-regex
                                   (1 'highlight-indentation-face)))))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))

;;;###autoload
(defun highlight-indentation-set-offset (offset)
  "Set indentation offset localy in buffer, will prevent
highlight-indentation from trying to guess indentation offset
from major mode"
  (interactive
   (if (and current-prefix-arg (not (consp current-prefix-arg)))
       (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))
     (list (read-number "Indentation offset: "))))
  (set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-offset) offset)
  (when highlight-indentation-mode
    (highlight-indentation-mode)))


;;;
;;; Copyright (C) Kresten Krab Thorup
;;; Available under Apache License, Version 2.
;;;
;;; This minor mode will highlight the indentation of the current line
;;; as a vertical bar (grey background color) aligned with the column of the
;;; first character of the current line.
;;;
(defface highlight-indentation-current-column-face
  ;; Fringe has non intrusive color in most color-themes
  '((t :inherit fringe))
  "Basic face for highlighting indentation guides."
  :group 'highlight-indentation)

;; used to hold the last regex we installed
(defvar highlight-indentation-current-column-regex nil)

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode
  highlight-indentation-current-column-mode
  "Hilight Indentation minor mode displays
a vertical bar corresponding to the indentation of the current line"
  :lighter " |"

  (when highlight-indentation-current-column-regex
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil highlight-indentation-current-column-regex))

  (set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-current-column-regex) nil)
  (cond (highlight-indentation-current-column-mode
          (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'highlight-indentation-current-column-post-command-hook nil t))
         (t
          (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'highlight-indentation-current-column-post-command-hook t)

          (font-lock-fontify-buffer))))

(defun highlight-indentation-current-column-post-command-hook ()
  "This hook runs after every keystroke"
  (when highlight-indentation-current-column-regex
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil highlight-indentation-current-column-regex))
  (let ((indent (save-excursion (back-to-indentation) (current-column))))
    (when (and highlight-indentation-current-column-mode
               (> indent 1))
      (let* ((re (format "^ \\{%d\\}\\( \\)" indent))
             (arg `((,re (1 'highlight-indentation-current-column-face prepend)))))
        (set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-current-column-regex) arg)
        (font-lock-add-keywords nil arg))))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))

(defun turn-on-highlight-indentation-mode ()
(interactive)
  (highlight-indentation-mode 1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-indentation-mode
  highlight-indentation-mode turn-on-highlight-indentation-mode)

(global-highlight-indentation-mode 1)

(provide 'highlight-indentation)
```

Comment: `c-font-lock-fontify-region: Symbol's function definition is void: nil` again.

Comment: I'm not seeing that error using the exact code in this answer, so you may need to bisect your user configuration file to find the error elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I am just removed all from my config file except of some default  code, and the code `(setq debug-on-error t)     
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/constantine/.emacs.d/")     
(load "highlight-indentation.el")`. And your code in the add-on file -- an error remains the same. But I found a funny thing: I *can* open a file through `C-x C-f`. An error appears only when open through a file manager. Drag-n-drop works too.

Comment: If Emacs is not working properly with completely stripped down user configuration, or with zero user configuration, then it may be time to back-up your entire installation (to a safe location) and try out the most recent version of Emacs -- if you are up to the challenge, maybe even try out a developer build snapshot.  Depending on your OS, there are pre-built binaries of even the developer snapshots.

Comment: Yagamy Light: Run `emacs -Q` to inhibit all user and site-wide elisp, then use `M-x load-file` with the file lawlist has provided to verify the default behaviour. Which version of Emacs are you running? (`M-x emacs-version`)

Comment: @phils sorry, I somehow mislooked you comment. I'll try this evening.

Comment: @phils I just thought: no, of course all will be okay. The problem as I [revealed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357632/emacs-how-to-enable-a-mode-globally/24357879?noredirect=1#comment37663353_24357879) appears only if open a file via file manager. Version is `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you verified you have the same Emacs version when launching it both ways?  In other words, perhaps launching with the file manager is triggering a different Emacs installation (with different options).  For example, OSX comes with a very old version of Emacs in `/usr/bin` and it frequently causes problems for people under a variety of circumstances when they have another installation elsewhere on the same system -- e.g., they expect calling `Emacs` or `emacsclient` from the command-line will trigger the latest installation, when in actuality it is the older version.

Comment: Do you mean you have an external application (file manager) configured to launch Emacs when you double-click on a file (or some such) ? You'll clearly need to show us how that is configured.

Comment: @phils yep. I am using dolphin, and it configured via GUI(*Open with->other->development->emacs, check box "Remeber an application for this file type"*) lawlist: I can check it when come in home again, but I am sure that I have only the one Emacs installation. I am running Kubuntu, and I don't see a reason why here could be a one more instance.

Comment: Note that we'll want to know the exact command and arguments used when it runs Emacs.

Comment: @phils, I was partially confused: the problem appears if open via command line too. But I haven't seen it yet because I didn't tried to open a `.c(pp)` files -- the problem appears only with these. But drag'n'drop and `C-x C-f` works anyway. lawlist, yes, the version the same.

Comment: So from the command line, `emacs -Q file.cpp` triggers the problem?

Comment: @phils, as I said the problem could be seen only in the time of launch Emacs. I.e. if Emacs launched – whether with default settings or no – the problem in this time is not reproducible, because both drag'n'drop and `C-x C-f` works fine.

Comment: Ah . . . Perhaps all your *stuff* isn't fully loaded *before* the file is being viewed when Emacs launches.  Perhaps @phils has some ideas if that is the case.  Things like setting up the `auto-mode-alist`, before/after init hooks, emacs-startup-hook, major-mode hooks, and your global-mode *all* need to be loaded *BEFORE* your file gets viewed when Emacs launches.

Comment: I honestly have no idea whether that was a "yes" or a "no" to my question. You indicated that running `emacs file.cpp` from the command line would trigger the error (correct?). I then asked whether running `emacs -Q file.cpp` *also* triggers the error (yes? no?).

Comment: If you get errors with `emacs -Q` then Emacs is broken. If not, then something in your site-wide or user configuration is broken. In either case, try using the `--debug-init` command-line argument (e.g. `emacs --debug-init file.cpp`), and also add `(setq debug-on-error t)` to the top of your init file (as I'm still not sure at which point the error is triggered), and if that gives you a debug stack then edit the whole thing into the question.

Comment: @phils, `-Q` option force to ignore the lisp in `.emacs` file. As I [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357632/emacs-how-to-enable-a-mode-globally/24357879?noredirect=1#comment37663164_24357632) the error without the code to enable this addon isn't appears. But if you really insist, I can check it when back in home.

Comment: @phils I think I should mention also that I have copied the `.emacs` and an addons to my PC in a job, and all worked fine. Right now here is `GNU Emacs 23.4.1` version. Though I turned off after some time this addon -- it is too raw. The vertical guides is just ugly and not that comfortable, and the addon doesn't see a tabs. Btw, I don't see for some reason a notifications if someone place here a comment without mentioning me. Wrote just to let you know: if you will place such a comment after a long time, I perhaps could mislook it.

Comment: Aha. Sorry, I hadn't noticed that you'd established that already. (My mistake; the earlier comments were clear enough; it's just that there's a lot of them :). Please do show us the full debug stack trace, if you get one.