# 'Symbol's function definition is void: nil' which symbol?

Tags: emacs

I'm getting the following error when starting emacs: (as shown from the *messages* buffer):

```
c-font-lock-fontify-region: Symbol's function definition is void: nil
```

How do I track down what exactly is causing the error in this function?  debug-on-error is true, but it still doesn't give any more information here.

Comment: You and another gentleman -- that's two reports of a similar issue this week.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/24357632/2112489

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol is `nil`.
It does not name a function.

Generally speaking, to debug the error, you need to set `debug-on-error` to `t` and look at the `*Backtrace*` buffer.
If no `*Backtrace*` buffer appears (which is the case here), this means that the caller of the function which signals the error catches the error. You would need to chase the code looking for `condition-case` and disable it. Good luck with that :-(

Looking at the `c-font-lock-fontify-region` definition in `progmodes/cc-mode.el`, I see there

```
(funcall (default-value 'font-lock-fontify-region-function)
         new-beg new-end verbose)
```

which can easily cause the error if `(default-value 'font-lock-fontify-region-function)` is `nil`.

Comment: OK, looking at the function it claims about (c-font-lock-fontify-region), there are no uses of nil.  So the question remains: How do I find out which variable/function call is actually nil?

Comment: See edit - you need to look at the `*Backtrace*` buffer.

Comment: No *Backtrace* buffer appears, even with debug-on-error equal to t, but that did give enough information to determine that was the problem.

Comment: Note that Emacs 24.3 introduced the exceedingly useful (in such situations) `debug-on-message` variable.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a backtrace even if the error is caught by a `condition-case` you can try to `(setq debug-on-signal t)`.  This will trigger in many cases which aren't bugs, so it's something to use only occasionally because it can really get in the way, but it might be helpful in this particular case.